# Get JavaScript File Name?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get its filename by only using javascript?

**For example**

I want to get the string `somefile.js?v=32&b=2.2` inside that same javascript file.

Is it possible to get it **without** going through the script tag?

Comment: Read the post, before commenting (I said without going through the script tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filename using only for loading script text. After that this script text puts in javascript tag and executes.